# promise in express middleware won't resolve if res.json is invoked

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise

I have code that populates an express route. A promise from a model call is chained with one for an analytics call.

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
   myDataModel.makeDataCallPromise(req.body)
    .then((result) => {
         res.status(201).json(result);
         return makeAnalyticsCallPromise();
    })
    .then((val) => {
      console.log('VAL', val);
    })
    .catch(next);
});
```

Problem is, the last *then* never fires. It *does* fire if I comment out the response call. Why is that?

I'm relatively new to promises so I am assuming there is something obvious I am missing here.

Comment: send the response after the second call.

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) `result` is not what you think it is and `res.json(result)` throws an exception which will cause the `.catch()` block to get control, not the `.then()` block or 2) `makeAnalysticsCallPromise()` never resolves it's promise or it rejects.

Comment: @jfriend00 As he mentioned that when he comments the response line, it works so it has to be 1 and not 2.

Comment: I'd suggest you add `console.log(result)` right before `res.status(201).json(result);` and make sure it's always what you are expecting it to be.